# Consequences of oAuth tokens ending up in the wrong hands

Tags: security, authentication, oauth, facebook-login

I am looking for a more secure method of authentication for my website than the conventional username and password. I am trying to minimise the amount of data I store about my users, and I've opted to implement social login functionality.

In the event of a hacker gaining access to a database, what are the consequences of them obtaining the access tokens? Is this data less sensitive than an email address & password, for instance?

Also, an explanation on which tokens are given when a user signs in for the first time would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens give the caller certain permissions in the application. [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) defines an application defined [scope](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.3) that limits what the caller can do inside the application (for example only retrieve the account balance).

Username/password combinations typically give full access to the application (make payments/transfers etc).

Access tokens are typically safer as they have a much shorter lifetime than username/password combinations. If you lose your access token, the attacker only has a limited timeframe in which access to your data can be gained.

Also, access tokens do not have to be stored in a database. They are verified via digital signatures. [OAuth refresh tokens](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5) are typically stored on a database. However, the client needs the client id and client secret to use the refresh token to get a new access token.

Comment: So, if I opted to use oAuth and a hacker managed to intrude on my database, what damage could be done?

Comment: If implemented correctly, not much. Besides only storing the refresh token, the auth server should store the client id and a salted hash of the client secret (just like storing passwords). This makes that the attacker needs to find the client secret before he/she can use the refresh token. Finding the secret from a salted hash is very expensive in computer time if a correct (slow) hashing algorithm is used.